# fetch web service addresses used by a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services

I'd like to connect to a web service (using python) without going through a website.

The problem is that the website uses multiple web services with dynamic addresses. The only way I know how to check the web service address is to load the website in a browser, open the developer tools and check the web services column.

Is there a way I can check what the web service addresses are using Python?

Comment: You can look into [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse HTML pages and find links in them.

Comment: @Ralf thanks for the suggestion but the webservice URLs aren't in the html source of the page